# Нужна ли запятая ПОСЛЕ слова "ХОТЯ" в предложении: Хотя, чему я удивляюсь?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая ПОСЛЕ слова "ХОТЯ" в предложении:

> Хотя, чему я удивляюсь?

Или правильно будет:

> Хотя чему я удивляюсь?

Помогите, совсем запуталась!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ХОТЯ** бывает **союзом** и **частицей**.

В вашем случае это, скорее, **союз**, аналогичный сочинительным противительным союзам НО, ОДНАКО. Ср.: *Однако чему я удивляюсь?*

**Запятая после ХОТЯ не ставится.**

***Хотя чему я удивляюсь?***

Бывают случаи, когда после ХОТЯ стоит многоточие как знак, показывающий умолчание, недосказанность: *Я, скорей всего, не смогу этого сделать. Хотя...*

Comment: @slava1947 А ведь вы, пожалуй, правы насчёт "только"! Спасибо! Придётся слегка вмешаться в собственный ответ).

Answer (score 2):

Иногда хочется вспомнить известную фразу: **никогда не говори никогда.**

«Хотя» никогда не бывает частицей?  Запятая после «хотя» никогда не ставится?
Если заглянуть  в Нацкорпус, то можно увидеть два варианта (с запятой и без запятой), которые различаются по интонации:

(1) На таком расстоянии, а достало! **Хотя чему удивляюсь?** В детстве увеличительным стеклом деревяшки выжигал, и на них солнце в миниатюре было, а здесь ― тысячи солнц! [Владимир Суворов, 1989]

(2) К счастью, это «тайное знание» было мне открыто гораздо позже. **Хотя, чему я радуюсь?** Я верила в другие вещи ― возможно, не такие прекрасные в своем маразматическом полете, но все же… [Е. Кучеренко, 2014 ]

Первый вариант более **частотный и стандартный**.  Союз ХОТЯ используется в качестве присоединительного союза.

А второй вариант  **более интересен.**  **Это уж точно не союз**, а значение у слова  «хотя»  здесь скорее вводное, его можно заменить сочетанием «с другой стороны».  Автор как бы размышляет, делает паузу:  хотя, если подумать…   Постановке запятой может способствовать структура предложения, например: *Хотя, я-то чему радуюсь?*

В устной речи встречаются такие паузы, иногда при записи их обозначают тире:Не послушаться ли этого зова, пока еще слышно? **Хотя ― зачем?** Дуб потому и растет по тысяче лет ― ведь ему время не нужно! [Владимир Дудинцев. (1956)]

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что паузу в рассматриваемом предложении можно (но не обязательно) обозначить многоточием или тире, но не запятой. Запятая была бы уместна в случае вводного значения частицы **хотя**, но я его здесь не вижу.

По поводу частицы **хотя**.

"Малый академический словарь" упоминает эту частицу как просторечный синоним частицы **хоть**. Хотя логичнее было бы назвать её устаревшей, поскольку ранее она активно использовалась. Тот же МАС цитирует Белинского:

> Мы не знаем даже, прочел ли Батюшков **хотя** одно стихотворение Пушкина.

Союз **хотя** подробно рассматривается в монографии Елены Урысон "Опыт описания семантики союзов". Там же приводятся примеры, подобные рассматриваемому в вопросе.

> (Пример 9) Петровы переехали и своего нового адреса не оставили (Q). Хотя
> спросите у соседей напротив, может быть, они больше знают (P).

Вот что говорит Е.Урысон об этих примерах:

> Данная лексема **хотя** обладает ярко выраженной синтаксической
> спецификой. Предложение **P**, вводимое ею, может располагаться только
> после  предложения  **Q**,  причем,  как  правило,  отделяется  от  него
> достаточно большой паузой (на письме предложения **P** и **Q** часто
> разделяются точкой). Перед нами, очевидно, фразовая частица.
> Существенно, что примеры (8)—(10) сильно отличаются от (1)—(3) [примеры с обычным союзом **хотя** — *grizzly*]
> семантически: в данном случае ни ситуация **P** не может
> интерпретироваться как препятствие для ситуации **Q**, ни, наоборот,
> ситуация **Q** не может быть препятствием для **P**.

Поскольку цитируемая монография посвящена союзам, автор говорит далее, что приведенные значения частицы **хотя** в ней не будут рассматриваться и отсылает читателя к работе А.Ф. Прияткиной, которую мне не удалось найти.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что нет вводного значения. Это колебание в оценке факта, события, например: Всё это кажется удивительным. Хотя, чему я удивляюсь?  Можно заменить вводным словом "впрочем". Значение вводности  мне кажется вполне возможным (в авторском понимании), другое дело - как его обозначить?  К чему эти запреты: тире можно, а запятую  - ни в коем случае.

Comment: @Sharon Вот я напишу так: *Всё это кажется удивительным. Но, чему я удивляюсь?* Если я буду настаивать, что "но" здесь вводное слово, многие меня поймут. А это усложняет взаимопонимание. Если очень нужно поставить ударение на "но" и создать паузу, лучше в качестве авторского знака использовать не запятую, а другой знак. Запреты нужны для того, чтобы не мешать языку выполнять свою основную функцию — обеспечивать взаимопонимание между людьми.

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то не ожидала, что ответите. Помните, как раньше говорили посыльным в ответ на письмо: «ответа не будет». Я же напишу так. Союз «но»  в вашем примере не имеет уступительного значения и не может заменить слово «хотя». (Меня вообще огорчает привычка одно заменять другим: грамматика – это же всё-таки не обменный пункт с заданным курсом.) И теперь  по поводу взаимопонимания.  В соответствии с авторским желанием,  пауза после «хотя» должна выразить сомнение и некоторое раздумье. (Знаки препинания для того и нужны,  чтобы обозначить авторскую мысль.)

Comment: Сомнение же выражают вводные слова, которые в начале предложения обособляются  запятой или тире (например, вводное слово «главное»). Вы считаете, что паузу после  «хотя» можно обозначить «многоточием или тире, но не запятой». А какова будет ФУНКЦИЯ у этого обособленного «хотя» ? Союз, частица? Неужели союз или частицу можно обособить тире. Их вообще-то можно обособлять? (Извините, если что-то показалось вам невежливым.)

Comment: Sharon: _Неужели союз или частицу можно обособить тире. Их вообще-то можно обособлять?_ === Союз? Можно. См. примеры: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=poetic&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&ext=10&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=Но&gramm1=&flags1=bdash%2Cadot&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=

Comment: Спасибо, slava1947, я очень люблю ваши примеры, просто поставили точку в дискуссии.  Интонационное тире в стихотворном тексте и всё такое. Вот уж не надо было мне писать последнюю фразу по тому же принципу – никогда не говори «никогда» и ничего не обобщай. Мне кажется, я уже заранее видела этот  ваш текст, когда еще только составляла комментарий.

Comment: Итак, неправильная запятая изгнана, законные права тире восстановлены. А как иначе, ведь только тире бывает интонационным, а интонационных запятых нет. Так что же, придется согласиться? Хотя нет, всё-таки не соглашусь. При постановке тире пауза подчеркнутая, ясно обозначенная,  а мне такая пауза не нужна. У меня даже не пауза, а выделение ударением слова "хотя". Точно также обозначается  вводное слово, обособленное запятой. Так что нарушение авторского права явно имеет место.