# Расстановка запятых. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Дорогие знатоки, выручайте!

"А(,) хотя(,) все равно!"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли запятая ПОСЛЕ слова "ХОТЯ" в предложении: Хотя, чему я удивляюсь?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462194/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%a1%d0%9b%d0%95-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%a5%d0%9e%d0%a2%d0%af-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что правильным будет вариант без знаков: ***А хотя все равно!***

Здесь "а хотя" — это **союзное соединение**, где А — сопоставительный союз, а ХОТЯ имеет уступительное значение.

В целом они обозначают **изменение мнения**. К примеру, пользователь склонялся к выбору одного варианта, но потом решает, что разницы между ними нет.

Здесь запятая после "а хотя" не ставится, так как в кратком предложении сделать паузу затруднительно. Но в других случаях постановка знака возможна.

Примеры:

***А хотя нет**… по-моему, и правда несколько.*

***А хотя**… ладно, на пять минут!*

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Почему нет запятой после "по-моему"?

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны. Это связка обычных союзов.

Comment: А если 'хотя' здесь деепричастие?)

Comment: Это не деепричастие))

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!