Нужна ли запятая после «хотя»?
Нужна ли запятая после "хотя" в таком предложении:

Хотя(,) попади наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы
учебную революцию.


https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462194/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%a1%d0%9b%d0%95-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%a5%d0%9e%d0%a2%d0%af-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%8c

• Я думаю, что в этом предложении союз "хотя" имеет значение но, однако.
Из БТС:
хотя, союз. 2. Соединяет противопоставляемые члены предложения; однако, но.
• Вот что о такой ситуации говорится у Розенталя (Запятая на стыке двух союзов):

5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза:
<...>
3) после союза но запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: Но, если далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.); Но когда он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);
4) после союза однако запятая обычно ставится: Однако, если обстоятельства того потребуют, я в стороне стоять не буду.

• Фрагмент предложения "попади наша четверка на другой факультет" выступает в роли придаточной части (с союзом "если").
• Ставить или не ставить запятую?
Это зависит от предыдущего контекста, от значения союза, от наличия или отсутствия паузы при чтении.
• Примеры
С запятой (бо́льшая часть):
Хотя, попади мы в Германию-2006, шансы на поездку я имел бы хорошие (И. Рабинер, В. Евсеев);
Хотя, попади мой брат в такую ситуацию, вел бы я себя так? (В. Лей);
Хотя, попади он в мою ситуацию, не стал бы так всуе упоминать похоронные принадлежности (А. Комов);
Хотя , попади она в руки чужому человеку , он самого важного из нее все равно не возьмет (М. Шахов);
Хотя, попади вы к варварам, сбылась бы ваша золотая мечта — выйти замуж... (И. Коняева).
Без запятой:
Хотя попади ты туда, узнала бы, насколько доброй была к тебе Танте Хелен (Ли Бардуго);
Хотя попади туда представители «Загат», они, вероятно, вызвали бы самого шустрого водителя, лучше всего Михаэля Шумахера... (Г. Лумис).

Хотя, попади наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Комментарий к теме
На вопрос было дано три ответа, причем в лучших оказался как раз третий. Что-то неточно или неверно было в первых двух, а там исправлено? Или в чем там дело? Все проблемы, как мне думается, возникают при неточном определении грамматики, поэтому с нее и начну.
1. Употребление повелительного наклонения (императива) в значении сослагательного
Пункт 4. Употребление одних наклонений в значении других
Разные наклонения в определенных случаях могут иметь близкие значения и, следовательно, употребляться вместо друг друга. (1) Повелительное наклонение в значении сослагательного: Приди на час раньше, ничего бы не случилось. Ср.: Если бы пришел...
Источник
2. Фразеологизированные конструкции со значением обусловленности в теме СПП
   Фрагмент предложения "попади наша четверка на другой 
   факультет" выступает в роли придаточной части (с союзом 
   "если").

Использована фразеологизированная конструкция со значением обусловленности, построенная по модели: глагол в форме повелит. наклонения в придаточном — глагол в форме сослагат. наклонения в главной части. Союз в придаточном предложении отсутствует, но при этом предложение полностью соответствует определению СПП с придаточным условии, а именно: придаточное называет ирреальное условие, при котором могла бы осуществиться ситуация в главной части (контрфактический тип предложения).
ВЫВОД. Это не фрагмент, а полноценное придаточное предложение со значением ирреального условия.
3. О союзе ХОТЯ  значении НО, ОДНАКО
 Я думаю, что в этом предложении союз "хотя" имеет значение 
 но, однако.

С этими союзами лучше сначала познакомиться не по толковым словарям, а по грамматическим источникам, например в Русской корпусной грамматике.
Союзы хотя и хоть
Основные уступительные союзы хотя и хоть. Эти два наиболее частотных уступительных союза выражают уступительное значение в САМОМ ЧИСТОМ виде, причем ХОТЯ стилистически нейтрален, а ХОТЬ носит разговорный характер: Союзы хотя и хоть выражают идею о том, что при наличии ситуации X естественной была бы ситуация, противоположная Y: Хотя шел дождь, они пошли гулять [естественно было бы остаться дома]. Эти союзы вводят валентность «препятствия» – ситуации X, которая должна была помешать, наступлению Y, но не смогла.
Союз НО:
(1) НО «ненормального следствия»: Шел дождь, но он не взял зонт.
(2) НО «противоположной оценки» (из двух компонентов, выражающих противоположную оценку, тот, который идет вторым, важнее): Она красивая, но глупая [важнее глупость]; Она глупая, но красивая [важнее красота] [Санников 2008];
Союз ОДНАКО:
К союзу НО близок необиходный союз однако. Он употребителен, с соответствующими стилистическими ограничениями, во многих контекстах, аналогичных но «ненормального следствия» и но «противоположной оценки»:
(1) однако «ненормального следствия»: Она получила хорошее образование, однако не может найти работу.
(2) однако «противоположной оценки» (из двух компонентов, выражающих противоположную оценку, тот, который идет вторым, важнее): Она очень способная, однако не получила хорошего образования.
ВЫВОД ПО СОЮЗАМ
Хотя, попади наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Из словаря для союза ХОТЯ. Соединяет придаточные уступительные предложения и обороты; несмотря на то, что. Соединяет противопоставляемые члены предложения; однако, но.
Нет сомнения в том, что в заданном предложении речь идет о придаточных уступительных предложениях, но никак не о противопоставляемых членах предложения. Союз ХОТЯ, выражающий значение уступки в наиболее чистом виде,  отнесен к контексту.
Ситуация из контекста касается конкретного факультета, где устроили "учетную революцию". Но дело не в факультете, а в четверке друзей, которые устроили бы такую революцию на любом факультете.
Попробуем сделать замену: Но, попади наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Союз ХОТЯ может выражать противительно-уступительное значение и замена союзом НО возможна, но где здесь значение «ненормального следствия»? Ведь следствия как раз никакого и не было, так как речь идет об ирреальной ситуации: устроили бы.
P. S. Тема дискуссионная,  а это критика всех ответов.   В первых двух ответах, с верными по существу решениями, оказалось недостаточно информации и ссылок для того, чтобы тема была полностью ясна. В третьем ответе все это есть, но как раз эта информация и вызывает сомнения как недостаточно обоснованная и проверенная. Есть о чем задуматься всем (отвечающим и голосующим).

Однозначности в решении я не вижу.
Хотя — это присоединительный союз, а в этих случаях по Розенталю постановка запятой зависит от вида союза. В частности после союзов И, А запятая обычно не ставится, после союза НО она факультативная. Возможно, после союза ХОТЯ тоже факультативная.
Примеры предложений:
Но все-таки, не попади я в армию, вряд ли бы со мной такое случилось вообще.
И попади тогда мой блокнот в руки бдительного комсомольца, мне, как идеологическому работнику, мало не показалось бы.
Поэтому, попади он к нему, его певческая карьера могла сложиться самым непредсказуемым образом.
Варианты:
ХотЯ, попади наша четверка на другОй факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Хотя попадИ наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
О грамматике предложения: употребление одних наклонений в значении других.
Разные наклонения в определенных случаях могут иметь близкие 
значения и, следовательно, употребляться вместо друг друга.
1) Повелительное наклонение в значении сослагательного: 
Приди на час раньше, ничего бы не случилось. Ср.: Если бы 
пришел... 

СТАВИТЬ ИЛИ НЕ СТАВИТЬ ЗАПЯТУЮ?
Решение такое: все зависит от лексического наполнения предложений, от фонетической сочетаемости союза и первой части предложения. При отсутствии паузы и запятой первая часть должна читаться в одну фонетическую фразу, а все предложение делится на две части.
Чем ближе мы к такому идеалу, тем больше вероятность отсутствия запятой, и наоборот. Если использовать союз хоть,то его легче вписать в предложение. Чем короче глагол — то же самое. А контексты, значения союзов и прочее — это дело десятое, рассуждения да и только.
Это и по правилам видно: А, И (не отделяются запятой), НО (факультативное решение), ОДНАКО (отделяется запятой).
Некоторые примеры:
Хоть приди Орфей возмутительных песен, так никто с места не тронется!
А приди это письмо чуть раньше, оно могло бы и повлиять на принятие решения.
Хотя начни возражать, еще хуже будет.
Кстати, первая часть — это не фрагмент, а полноценное придаточное предложение со значением условия.

Ну что долго рассусоливать: нужна.
Тут повелительное наклонение конвертируется в придаточное, как-то так.
Хотя, попади наша четверка на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Хотя, если б наша четверка попала на другой факультет, мы и там устроили бы учебную революцию.
Уходим от двух "бы", хотя я и редуцировада одну штучку в "б".
Громоздко ж.
